# How to compile and move to another folder a bunch of sass files using Gulp?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp

How can I compile and move `sass` files from `sass/**` folder to `css/**` directory using Gulp?

```
src('sass/**/*.sass')

dest('css/**/*.css')
```

PS: every `sass` file must have it's compiled `css`-version (without file-concatenation)

PPS: I can't use `sass --w sass:css` method, because I also have to watch other files (`.js`, `.jade`) for changes

Comment: why cant you use just `sass --watch sass:css`? if all files in sass directory are partials - you can remove '_' from partial name and it will compile to the separate css file

Comment: @qw1564, nice thought. but I have a gulp watching for changes in files not only `.sass`, but also `.js` and `.jade`. so I need a more flexible solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

// styles task : for generating css
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
});

// watch task : which will watch for changes, and run styles task
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});
```

Then in the terminal just run the following

```
gulp watch
```

Comment: this way i have to run this command every time I need to update my files, right? i need a solution, which will work on background and still allow me to watch different file extentions, not just sass.

Comment: @karl_doyle, you're genious! thanx for help!